# Using typescript baseurl and paths breaks React-Router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am trying to set baseUrls and paths in the tsconfig, however whenever I change the baseURL I recieve the following error

> ```
> ./node_modules/react-router/es/StaticRouter.js
> 120:40-54 'history' does not contain an export named 'createLocation'.
> ```

I have tried setting the node_path in env config and moving the path and baseurl to a seperate typescript file as was suggested in a github thread, however this did not work.

So here is what I have as of now in the Tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "paths": {
      "sagas/*": ["sagas/*"],
      "src/*": ["./*"],
      "*": [ "node_modules/@types/*", "*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "lib",
    "tests",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "__mocks__",
    "__test__",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

Please note changing baseUrl back to `'.'` fixes the issue but the custom paths will no longer work

Typescript version is 3.3.1

Comment: is the structure in yarn workspaces ?

Comment: no using npm for installs and haven't touched yarn yet. Actually not familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

Alright a bit of a dolt here.

Had a History.ts file in the `"src"` directory. So changing the `baseUrl` to `src` was resulting in that location being checked first even in the third party libraries. So needless to say **that** history object did not contain those definitions

Some folder/file reorganization fixed the issue